# Merge 2 database in wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress, merge

I am working on a website with my company. We have a Dev and a Prod version.
For some reason someone modified somethng on the prod and not on the dev and i want to know a way to take his changes and merge it with the DB on the dev version.

It'll be the same if we want to update our site in the future.
I work on an Hotel website (that's why we use wordpress btw) and we can leave comments on it. If we are the day 1 and we clone the prod to the dev to work on something, the day 15 (for exemple) we want to push our work to the prod. All the comments between the day 1 and the day 15 will not be saved bc we will replace the db.

I've tried different plugin but none of them were doing what i asked ... 
Redgate didn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a simple solution to what you are looking for.

Think of this options:

1) Do you have backup for the data base. Just load it.
If not, you should always back up your system.

2) If there are no other developments or changes to the dev schema, just drop the dev DB and copy prod to dev.

And any way, no meter what you choose. Please back up the data bases before making any other changes.

Comment: Ty for the response. I have no trouble with backups but between the time i start to work on the dev and the time i've finished someone may have left a comment on my website wich will not appear on the dev part and that is currently my problem. I can not merge my changes to the DB of the prod easily. But i guess there is no way to do it.

Comment: Yes, I understand. 
Sometime the easiest way to do something is manually. 
If it's only comments, and there are not many pages, just check if there are new comments, or even just dump the relevant table and migrate it.